# Using an existing cookie authentication's Identity state on a custom login page

Tags: identityserver3

I've been tasked with integrating IDS3 into an existing legacy MVC application that I migrated to OWIN which uses CookieAuthentication. Via the awesome examples project, I have managed to get a simple setup working with a custom user service, custom login page, and a code-flow test client.

I am now attempting to solve this requirement: if a user is already logged in via existing cookie authentication and initiates a code-flow via our test client, automatically log them in to IDS3 so that they are not prompted to enter their credentials again. Here's the not-working code to show my thought process:

```
[Route("identity/logintest", Name = "ids3-login")]
public ActionResult IdsLogin(string id)
{
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var user = ctx.Authentication.User;

    // If they're already logged in via cookie auth, automatically
    // log them in to IDS3 and send them on their way
    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var env = ctx.Environment;

        env.IssueLoginCookie(new IdentityServer3.Core.Models.AuthenticatedLogin
        {
            Subject = User.Identity.Name,
            Name = User.Identity.Name,
        });

        var msg = env.GetSignInMessage(id);
        var returnUrl = msg.ReturnUrl;

        env.RemovePartialLoginCookie();

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    // Otherwise show the login form as usual
    return View();
}
```

If I log in as a user via cookie auth, the value of user.Identity is not populated with that information and therefore IsAuthenticated is false. I think I have a pseudo-understanding of why this fails currently: I'm asking for the Authentication value of the context associated with IDS3, not the one for my MVC application that has the cookie authentication I'm after. (Which is conceptually confusing, since that controller is a part of my MVC application.)

This is probably less of an IDS3 question and more of an OWIN question, but my hope is that someone else has tried to implement this hacky approach before and can point me in the right direction. Hopefully when I run through the all of the OWIN samples I found on http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/owin-katana things will make more sense, but right now I'm stuck.

Startup.cs for reference (didn't include the custom user service code as it's basically copy paste from the CustomLoginPage example project):

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = AutofacConfig.Configure();

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();

        ConfigureAuthentication(app);
        ConfigureIdentityServer(app);
    }

    private static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
        });
    }

    private static void ConfigureIdentityServer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .UseInMemoryScopes(StandardScopes.All);

        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver =>
            resolver.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IUserService>());

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "test",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            Factory = factory,

            AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
            {
                EnableLocalLogin = true,

            }
        }

        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if a user is already logged in via existing cookie authentication and initiates a code-flow via our test client, automatically log them in to IDS3 so that they are not prompted to enter their credentials again

If you implement `PreAuthenticate` in your custom user service then you can detect your custom cookie to know the user has already authenticated. You can then issue a valid `AuthenticationResult` from `PreAuthenticate`. We have a samples that shows something like this.

I'm not sure about the rest of the code you have above -- I'm somewhat confused about why you have it and where it fits in, so I'm hesitant to comment on why it may or may not be working.

Comment: Trying to implement PreAuthenticate was actually my first attempt, but I could not figure out the detecting custom cookie bit. My first attempt was to identify the user by injecting an IOwinEnvironment, creating the OwinContext from that, then checking the status of Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, which was always false even if I was logged in to custom cookie auth. Attempt #2 was to try to pull my auth cookie from Request, decrypt it, then check auth from there. Is that what you're suggesting by detecting the custom cookie, or is there another option I'm missing?

Comment: Well, you said it's in a custom cookie -- if you have the owin context then you should be able get to the cookie. Accessing User.IsAuthenticated might not be the right thing -- but you should be able to call AuthenticateAsync to get the katana code to check the cookie.

Comment: Success! Thank you for the assistance. I was able to retrieve the cookie and the claims identity within it. I was apparently using some outdated techniques for trying to decrypt the cookie, but a few days of not staring at it made it jump out when I revisited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see that someone needed the same hacky solution as me. I had to use old Membership cookie to authenticate user with IdentityServer. My solution was pretty simple - I was not using *user.Identity.IsAuthenticated* for this, but read the cookie value from Response directly as Raw value and used Membership classes to decrypt the user name from it. By this I was not having trouble with different cookie providers for authentication. As the whole concept is hacky anyway I did not mind to read the cookie manually in this case.